# Multipart-form with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, axios

I want to post an image along JSON from axios to Django Rest Framework, I'm using multipart-form as mentioned in the documentation but nothing is working. need your help.

Comment: please provide the code

Answer (score 0):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    image = request.FILES['fileToUpload']
    request = request.POST['ref_no']
```

Post man request should be like this:

[image]